# MFMailComposeViewController issue with From address

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, sendmail

I send mail using following code:

```
- (IBAction)sendMailPressed:(id)sender
{
    Class mailClass = (NSClassFromString(@"MFMailComposeViewController"));
    if (mailClass != nil)
    {
        // We must always check whether the current device is configured for sending emails
        if ([mailClass canSendMail])
        {
            [self displayComposerSheet];
        }
        else
        {
            [self launchMailAppOnDevice];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        [self launchMailAppOnDevice];
    }
}

// Displays an email composition interface inside the application. Populates all the Mail fields.
-(void)displayComposerSheet
{
    MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;


    [picker setSubject:self.strMailSubject];

    // Attach pdf to the email
    NSURL *urlToLoad = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:self.strSorce withExtension:self.strExtention];
    NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlToLoad];
    [picker addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"application/pdf" fileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@", self.strSorce, self.strExtention]];

    //  [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    [[Singleton sharedInstance] pushModalViewController:picker whereCurrentController:self animated:YES];
    [picker release];
}


// Dismisses the email composition interface when users tap Cancel or Send. Proceeds to update the message field with the result of the operation.
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error
{
    // Notifies users about errors associated with the interface
    switch (result)
    {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:

            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    [[Singleton sharedInstance] popModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}


// Launches the Mail application on the device.
-(void)launchMailAppOnDevice
{
    NSString *recipients = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"mailto:&subject=%@", self.strMailSubject];

    NSString *email = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", recipients];
    email = [email stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:email]];
}
```

And I get this view:
[image]

But I need this view (please, pay attention only to From string, not to the image).

I don't know how to make From string appear

[image]

Comment: you can use either `setBccRecipients` or `setCcRecipients`. Check this [reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: I outlined From string in the second image, look at the topic. In your example I will see "cc: gkfanatic@gmail.com", but I want to see "from: gkfanatic@gmail.com"

Comment: I want to see sender's address "from: sender@sender.com"

Comment: You can use "setPreferredSendingEmailAddress" for iOS 11 and newer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `setCcRecipients:` for this in your code.

Comment: but I will not see From string, only cc with proper address

Comment: What do you mean not see from string?

Comment: @Vishal first time i not know that its problem for cc but when your answer i seen the understand whats the problem bro.. short and good answer which cove exact the point .. :)

Comment: I outlined From string in the second image, look at the topic. In your example I will see "cc: gkfanatic@gmail.com", but I want to see "from: gkfanatic@gmail.com"

Comment: oh no yaar please hum dost a6e he yaar .. dosti me jo maja a wo dusre menahi yaar

Comment: Ok frnd to hum hai he but mai to kahunga...ranawat2865@gmail.com ye meri facebook ID hai Plz add kar lena...

Comment: I want to see sender's address "from: sender@sender.com"

Comment: I need to see the sender's address, so @Paras code will not help me, each user has different email address

Comment: @PaulGalavic now i update the answer.. and here you get email id dynamic with your requirement .. right?? then just set that string variable instead of yourStringName variable from my answer..

Answer (score 2):

just add this line in your `displayComposerSheet`  method after create `MFMailComposeViewController` and also just set the `NSArray` with Recipients names...

```
 NSString *strFullName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"From : %@",yourSenderEmailAddress];/// here write your email address which dynamic get from your string 
 NSArray *arrRecipients = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:strFullName, nil];
[picker setCcRecipients:arrRecipients];
```

I Update code with one example also...

Also Vishal's Answer is also right, i just complete it..

Comment: but I will not see From string

Comment: what your mean paul?? means from which you want to see that??

Comment: @PaulGalavic see you have a string in which you have a email address right then just store that string in array and the set it to Recipients , see the exmple which i put in answer :)

Comment: I outlined From string in the second image, look at the topic. In your example I will see "cc: gkfanatic@gmail.com", but I want to see "from: gkfanatic@gmail.com"

Comment: then add From: before your this email address string but why you want that??? it is useless

Comment: I want to see sender's address "from: sender@sender.com"

Comment: just use this             NSString *strFullName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"From : %@",yourStringName]; and the add this strFullName in array try now

Comment: @PaulGalavic you got it or not??

Answer (score 0):

If more than one mail account have been added, the from field will be visible in order to select the sender from multiple accounts.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any way to set the From: field of MFMailComposeViewController programmatically, probably for security reasons. The owner of the device has control over what accounts are registered on the device and therefore what the From: field is allowed to contain.

The From: field only shows if multiple email accounts have been configured on the device; that field then allows the user to pick which account to send from. If only one account exists on the device, it is not shown (it "goes without saying" which account is being used).

Answer (score 0):

You can use "setPreferredSendingEmailAddress" for iOS 11 and newer.